# Yearly Reputation Seems to be calculated wrong

Tags: support, reputation-leagues

I'm looking at the yearly calculations and the numbers don't add up:

[image]

If you add up the numbers on the total reputation changes there should be 7,491 users who have gained 2500 or more reputation.  However you can see I've only earned 1909 reputation yet I'm rank lower than 7,491.

How is this possible, are the calculations on reputation change aggregated differently?

Comment: Why do you think that there should be 7491 users with more than 2500? From what I see, there should be 4945 users.

Comment: 7107 is a higher rank than 7491.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The numbers in the reputation change list are all users who reached the threshold. They already include the users in higher categories.

There are 4945 users with more than 2500 reputation change **of which** 1866 have gained more than 5000 rep.

Comment: Ah I see now I assumed they were exclusive